# Use explicitly the POST request values in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, curl

I have some code to generate crypto-currency wallet using a Spring MVC project.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generateAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper> generateAddress(@RequestParam("walletName") String walletName,
                                                         @RequestParam("currencyName") String currencyName, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String wallet_Name = request.getParameter("walletName");
    String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currencyname");

    System.out.println("wallet_Name = " + wallet_Name + " , currency_Name = " + currency_Name);

    // return if the wallet name or the currency is null
    if (Objects.isNull(wallet_Name) || Objects.isNull(currency_Name)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

    WalletInfo walletInfo = walletService.generateAddress(wallet_Name);

    if (Objects.isNull(walletInfo)) {
        return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

    WalletInfoWrapper walletInfoWrapper = new WalletInfoWrapper();
    walletInfoWrapper.setName(walletInfo.getName());

    return new ResponseEntity<WalletInfoWrapper>(walletInfoWrapper, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Now, I make this `POST` request,

```
curl -X POST -d "walletName=zyx&currencyName=bitcoin" http://localhost:8080/rest/generateAddress
```

I would like to have the `wallet_Name` and `currency_Name` separated and printed as provided in the code. However, after I make the `POST` request, I see nothing in the console.

```
        String wallet_Name = request.getParameter("walletName");
        String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currencyname");

        System.out.println("wallet_Name = " + wallet_Name + " , currency_Name = " + currency_Name);
```

I also tried to `POST` using the `JSON` format of data and I get no change. What's the issue here?

Comment: Please, write me the reason to downvote and I will modify/ delete the question. I'm slightly confused and had to ask it again. Btw, I have `deleted` the previous question asked.

Comment: Your method is for a POST, your `curl` is a POST, but you are talking about `GET` - I am confused - Also note that your parameters` and passed as `@RequestParam("walletName") String walletName,` arguments into your method

Comment: @ScaryWombat the question is indeed about the `POST` which should create the wallet with name and address. I use `GET` for checking the values which are created after the `POST`. What should I take note about the parameter? If there is a mistake, write it as an answer.

Comment: *I use GET for checking the values which are created after the POST* - this does not make sense.  You have the variables `walletName` and `currencyName` - they are posted to you - end of story

Comment: Don't you understand they are being `POST` as the wrong format? Carefully, read the question before downvote

Comment: I did not downvote

Comment: and if I don't understand it is because of your poor explanation - bye

Comment: Updated the question and make the scope precise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I would advice you to switch from using `System.out.println` and use a proper logger, such as `slf4j`, since you will probably want at one point to have all your output statements to a file.

There is something not right on how you use spring mvc.
Since you already have `@RequestPAram`s declared for your two fields, why not use them directly instead of doing `request.getPrameter("blah")`. So I would recommend either removing the `@RequestParam` and use the `HttpServletRequest` or vice versa.

Another thing that I saw here `String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currencyname");` you made a mistake. You should be doing `request.getParameter("currencyName")` (observe the N uppercase).

Here is my example for your request. I added both using `@RequestParam` and making use of `request.getParameter()`. It's your choice what you want to use. Recommendation nowadays is to use the `@RequestParam`.

```
@RestController
public class WalletController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/generateAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> generateAddress(@RequestParam("walletName") String walletName,
                                                  @RequestParam("currencyName") String currencyName, HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("walletName {} and currencyName {}", walletName, currencyName);
        String wallet_Name = request.getParameter("walletName");
        String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currencyName");
        logger.info("walletName {} and currencyName {}", wallet_Name, currency_Name);

        // DO other Stuff
        return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
    }
}
```

testing out the request:

```
curl -X POST -d "walletName=my-cool-wallet&currencyName=ETH" http://localhost:8080/generateAddress
```

watching the logs:

```
2017-08-14 10:11:29.972  INFO 29228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.controller.WalletController        : walletName my-cool-wallet and currencyName ETH
2017-08-14 10:11:29.972  INFO 29228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.controller.WalletController        : walletName my-cool-wallet and currencyName ETH
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should do a POST with a query parameter directly in the URL like the one below since you are trying to pass multiple parameters.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/rest/generateAddress?walletName=zyx&currencyName=bitcoin
```

Comment: This doesn't work and I assume this is not the correct answer

Comment: Hey, I pulled down the code and executed and it works for me. 

I am able to see the values split into their variables properly with your cURL statement as well as with what I have suggested. 

One thing I have noticed while executing in local though is that you have a bad variable name for currencyName

String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currency**n**ame");

String currency_Name = request.getParameter("currency**N**ame");